# Proving whether a function on the set of real sequences is a metric

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be the set of all real sequences , for $(x_n) , (y_n) \in S$ , let $d \Big((x_n) , (y_n) \Big) :=0 $ if $x_n=y_n , \forall n \in \mathbb Z^+$ otherwise $d \Big((x_n) , (y_n) \Big) :=\dfrac 1{\min \{n :x_n \ne y_n\}}$ , then is $d$ a metric ?

EDIT : I have only difficulty in proving the triangle inequality

Comment: Please provide context on the question at hand. Is this a homework problem? What have you tried?

Comment: This is also a duplicate question but I cannot find the original (it was posted a long time ago).

Answer (score 3):

Let $d(x, y) = \dfrac1a, \; d(y, z) = \dfrac1b, \; d(x, z) = \dfrac1c$.  Then $(y)$ agrees with $(z)$ till position $b-1$, $(x)$ agrees with $(z)$ till $c-1$, so clearly $(x)$ agrees with $(y)$ at least till position $\min(b-1, c-1)$.  Thus we have 
$$a \ge \min(b, c) \implies \dfrac1a \le \dfrac1{\min(b, c)} \le \dfrac1b+\dfrac1c$$

Comment: Where $\frac1{\min(b,c)} = \max(\frac1b, \frac1c)$ if you're confused about that.